# How to make "array of ArrayList" that contains "ArrayList<Integer>"?

Tags: java, arrays

How to make “array of ArrayList” that contains `ArrayList<Integer>`? I tried this

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] locOfDotCom = new ArrayList[3];
```

there is no error, but it didn't work. So how can I do it? I have tried other answers on SO but it is very confusing

Comment: there is no error but **look at the warning**

Answer (score 2):

Once you've done that, you'll just have an empty array. You'll need to loop through and create an `ArrayList<String>` in each slot afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make “array of ArrayList” that contains `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Simply use `List` in place of static array.

```
List<List<Integer>> locOfDotCom = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

**Always assign to interface type.**

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. The `LinkedList` makes sure that the `ArrayList` objects are always sorted in the same order, even if you add a new `ArrayList`.

Comment: What do you think about `ArrayList`? does it maintain the insertion order?

Comment: What is you point? Yes it does. Have I said something wrong?

EDIT: All lists maintain the insertion order. They are lists.

Comment: why you used `LinkedList`?

Comment: Because it brings benefits (over an ArrayList) when you insert new elements or remove elements. When you know the position of those elements.

Comment: but in your post you talked about "always sorted in the same order". Look at the OP question again. OP is not asking about which one to in between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

Comment: Exactly, so, if I want I can suggest him to use `LinkedList` and you have nothing to ask about because it isn't your question to begin with.